# where is the main file in this plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am looking through a no longer maintained plugin to see if perhaps I may want to revive it:

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/rate-this-page-plugin?order=name

but I cannot identify the main file, the one that would be named after the plugin in accordance with the WordPress Codex Plugin Handbook.

I thought perhaps it was this:

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/rate-this-page-plugin/tags/1.0/rtp-main.php

but I do not see a plugin header comment with the metadata about the plugin. Is this just a poorly written plugin or am I looking in the wrong place? I reviewed a few different files, I mean, the main file with the plugin metadata comment should not be that hard to find, should it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin header, and thus main plugin file, is located in [rate-this-page-plugin/trunk/rtp-load.php](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/rate-this-page-plugin/trunk/rtp-load.php).